# How to distinguish between own git remote and github?

Tags: git, github

I have my private git projects that I push to my private remote git server. These projects should not be uploaded to github.

Additionally I want to contribute to public github projects.

I have concerns that by mistake I could accidentally push one of the private projects to github.

Is there any trick or best practice how I can avoid any mistake here for sure?

Comment: Can you please go into more detail on the scenario you are afraid of?  What are the exact steps that you think would cause a private repo to be pushed to github by mistake.  I'm having trouble visualizing this.  I guess it seems similar to someone looking for a way to make sure they don't accidentally buy a car instead of a can of tuna.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have concerns that by mistake I could accidentally push one of the private projects to github

It would not be easy to make that mistake. Every local repo "knows" what remote repo it is syncing with; that knowledge does not magically change spontaneously.

Look in the local repo for one of the private project with `git remote -vv`. This will show you the names of known remotes with their URLs. If none of those URLs mentions GitHub — and I would bet dollars to donuts they do not — then the only way one of these projects could be pushed to GitHub is if you explicitly said something like

```
git push -u git@github.com:myUserName/myRepo.git master
```

where myRepo.git *already exists* on GitHub. (You cannot push to a GitHub repo that does not already exist; pushing does not *create* a remote repo.)

Well, what are the chances of that? I would say the chances are about the same as your saying `rm -rf *.*` — nothing can stop you from saying it, but you are not actually going to.

Comment: *I would say the chances are about the same as your saying `rm -rf *.*` — nothing can stop you from saying it, but you are not actually going to.* Unless, of course, you now fixate on not typing in `rm -rf *.*`, causing you to type it in. :-)